# How to return the row value based on condition of comparing 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanna write a MySQL query to extract the data as below:
Return the row with the transaction date < Moved date. In the case of item B, it's clear that there is only 1 row with transactoin date < Moved Date.
However, with item A, if transaction date < moved date of 2 rows, return the row with the min transaction date

Original table:

[image]

Desired Table:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your rules seem to be:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item order by transaction_date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and transaction_date < moveddate;
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Is there another way to do this without using the window function? I can't use over (partition...) in my program. Thank you

Comment: Why not?  It has been supported in MySQL since early 2018.

Answer (score 0):

You can have simple subquery to get this:

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE  (MOVEDDATE, ITEM) IN ( SELECT MIN(MOVEDDATE), ITEM
              FROM TABLE1 A GROUP BY ITEM);
```